# Reactjs does not read .env files

Tags: reactjs, firebase, environment-variables

Hello I create a web app with firebase
my .env files does not work

heres my code in firebase.js

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.AUTH_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSENGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.APPLE_ID
};
```

heres my .ENV code

```
API_KEY=Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AUTH_DOMAIN=xxxxxxxxxxxx
PROJECT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxx
STORAGE_BUCKET=mxxxxxxxxxx
MESSENGING_Sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
APPLE_ID=1:3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

heres where located the my .env

[image]

can guys explain why my .env does not read in my react? i search any question here in stack overflow but the same problem i got was in laravel i dont use laravel i use React JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react app all your envs should start with `REACT_APP_`

[More Info](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

Comment: Hello i already changed it and restart my server but i get the same error

Comment: Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).

Comment: Whats `.env` file name

Comment: it working right noew thnakj you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a react native project - I fixed it with the installation of `react-native-dotenv`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv